# Can't get a simple text-based fighting game function called from my html file to work properly (loops and if... else-statements)

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I'm new to JavaScript (and programming in general). I was just playing around with this script that checks how many combat rounds it takes for fighter1 to knock out fighter2 and writes out all the combat events to the page.

When I call the `fightClub();` function from my HTML-file, all that gets printed is "Test". How can I get this to work? Is my logic flawed?

Any help would be much appreciated! <3

```
const fighter1 = array ("Jimmy", 10, 2);

const fighter2 = array ("Chet", 10, 2);

function fightClub(fighter1, fighter2){
    document.write('Test');

    let hitcheck = math.ceil(math.random() * 10);
    while (fighter2[1] > 0){
        let roundNumber = 1;
        roundNumber++;
        if(hitcheck >= 5){
            fighter2[1] = fighter2[1] - fighter1[2];
            document.write('Round' + roundNumber);
            document.write(fighter1[0] + ' deals ' + fighter1[2] + ' damage to ' + fighter2[0]);
        }else {
            document.write('Round' + roundNumber);
            document.write(fighter1[0] + ' swung in the air and... missed ' + fighter2[0]);
        }
        if(fighter2[1] <= 0){
            document.write(fighter2[0] + ' was knocked out.');
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several syntax errors in your code. Fix them and you'll see the result.

Here it is:

```js
const fighter1 = ["Jimmy", 10, 2];

const fighter2 = ["Chet", 10, 2];

function fightClub(fighter1, fighter2){
    document.write('Test');

    let hitcheck = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10); // use 'Math' not math
    while (fighter2[1] > 0){
        let roundNumber = 1;
        roundNumber++;
        if(hitcheck >= 5){
            fighter2[1] = fighter2[1] - fighter1[2];
            document.write('Round' + roundNumber);
            document.write(fighter1[0] + ' deals ' + fighter1[2] + ' damage to ' + fighter2[0]);
        }else {
            document.write('Round' + roundNumber);
            document.write(fighter1[0] + ' swung in the air and... missed ' + fighter2[0]);
        }
        if(fighter2[1] <= 0){
            document.write(fighter2[0] + ' was knocked out.');
            break;
        }
    }
}

fightClub(fighter1, fighter2);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I missed those. Now I've moved out the declaration of roundNumber outside of the while loop, and moved the declaration of hitcheck inside it.
It now works as intended. Once again, thank you <3